# Issue concerning the uniqueness of the SDE of Bessel process

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading the book Bessel Processes, Schramm-Loewner Evolution, and the Dyson model of Makoto Katori. In chapter 1, the $D$-dimensional Bessel process $R_t^x$ is introduced and is defined as follows
$$R_t=\|B_t^x\|_2$$
where $B_t^x$ is a $D$-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $x\in\mathbb R^D\setminus\{ 0\}$. One can prove using Ito's formula that
$$R_t^x=\|x\|_2+\int^t_0\frac{1}{R_s^x}\sum_{i=1}^D B^{x_i}_s\,dB_s^{x_i}+\frac{D-1}{2}\int^t_0\frac{1}{R_s^x}\,ds$$
where $B_t^{x_i}$ is the $i$-th component of $B^x_t$.  Also note that Ito's formula only holds until the first hitting time of zero, but for $D\geq 2$ it will never hit zero with probability $1$. Now one can easily argue using Levy's characterization of Brownian motion that the second term of the expression above is a $1$-dimensiona standard Brownian motion, that is
$$\left(\int^t_0\frac{1}{R_s^x}\sum_{i=1}^D B^{x_i}_s\,dB_s^{x_i}\right)_{t\geq 
 0}$$
is a standard Brownian motion.

This is all basic, but now the confusion kicks in. Based on the observations above, the book just says that $R_t^x$ solves the SDE
$$\tag{1}dR_t^x=dW_t+\frac{D-1}{2R_t^x}\,dt$$
where $W_t$ is a standard BM different than the $B_t^{x_i}$ for $i=1,...,D$. I be like "What? Wait a minute? Didn't we lose properties about the very definition of $R_t^x$ by saying that?". Let me formulate this. Of course we have this filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathcal F_t,\mathbb P)$ in the background.  The problem is

> **Problem.**
>   Does the SDE in (1) with initial value $R_0^x=\|x\|_2$ has a strong unique solution in the sense that the solution of the SDE, say $R_t^x$ can be written as $ R_t^x=\|B_t^x\|_2$ for some $D$-dimensional BM $B_t^x$?

So you guys hopefully see that I'm only asking whether the definition of Bessel process and the SDE that it satisfies is consistent. I know that the solution of (1) is unique for $D\geq 2$ through uniqueness results from the book of Revuz-Yor for instance. But how do I make sure that the BM $W_t$ can be decomposed in terms of $B_t^{x_i}$...?

Many thanks! Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: Even the case $D=2$ would be nice...

Comment: What properties are you saying that we lose from defining the Bessel process as the solution to this SDE?

Comment: @RyanGreyling you see that $W_t$ is not just some Brownian motion. It is a specific Brownian motion given in terms of $B_t$. So my concern is whether we lose the fact that the Bessel process is the length of some $D$-dimensional Brownian motion. Does this somehow make sense?

Comment: Can you please use a dummy variable in integration? There is ambiguity when you don't do that.

Comment: @Ian of course, my bad, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $B$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownain motion ($d\ge 2$). Define the radial part $R$ as you have, then 
$$
A_t:=\int_0^t R^{-2}_s\,ds,\qquad t\ge 0,
$$
and finally the (time-changed) angular part 
$$
\Theta_u:={B_{\tau(u)}\over R_{\tau(u)}},\qquad u\ge 0,
$$
where 
$$
\tau(u):=\inf\{t>0: A_t>u\}.
$$
Then $R$ is the unique strong soution of (1), with $W$ defined as in the display just above (1), and $\Theta$ is a spherical Brownian motion *independent of* $R$. (The nature of $\Theta$ can be intuited from the polar-coordinates decomposition of the $d$-dimensioanl Laplacian.)  This independence means that the full $d$-dimensional Brownian motion $B$ cannot be recovered from the Bessel process $R$ (though of course the 1-dimensional Brownian motion $W$ can).

Going the other way, starting with a 1-dimensional Brownian motion $W$ and an independent spherical Brownian motion $\Theta$, one can solve (1) to get $R$, and then invert the above construction using $R$ and $\Theta$ to build a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion 
$$
R_t\cdot\Theta_{A_t},\qquad t\ge 0.
$$
For a nice discussion of these things see the first chapter of the first volume of the ** of **Rogers and Williams.

Comment: Many thanks! The answer, as I would expect is above my level. But when you say "going the other way" where $\Theta$ comes from? At that point we only have $W$, or?

Comment: Is the title of the book "Diffusions, Markov process and martingales"?

Comment: Yes to the title of the book.  As to $\Theta$, that has to be supplied independently of $W$.

Comment: Ow wait, I had the directions wrong. My main question is answered in the part "Then $R$ is the unique...", right? So there you say that we cannot say much with $W$ alone? And that leads to the conclusion that we cannot find a unique BM $B$ such that $R=\|B\|_2$?

Comment: Correct: In the passage from $B$ to $R$, information about the "angle" of $B$ is lost.

Comment: WOW! Your last comment!! Simple and beautiful explanation! Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, at what part exactly of chapter 1? I couldn't find related stuff, do they actually prove stuff with spherical BM or...?

Comment: Sorry, my memory was a little shaky on that reference.  See Chapter IV section 35 in the second edition of R&W.  This is in volume 2.

Comment: yes many thanks!!